# order of a complex number w.r.t. additive group

Tags: group-theory

We know that the least positive integer $n$ is said to be the order of an element $a$ if $a^n=1$ (multiplicative) or $na=0$ (additive). So what is the order of $a+ib$ where $a,b$ are non-zero?
Thanks

Comment: What is the group? Also, use English...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the group is $\mathbb{C}$ under addition, the order of $a+ib$ is finite if and only if there is a positive integer $n$ such that $n(a+ib) = 0$. This equation holds if and only if $na = 0$ and $nb = 0$, which forces $a=b=0$. Consequently, any nonzero complex number has infinite (additive) order.

If the group is $\mathbb{C}^\times$ under multiplication (i.e., the multiplicative group of all nonzero complex numbers), then an arbitrary element $z$ can be expressed in the form $z = re^{i\theta}$, where $r > 0$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then if $n$ is a positive integer, we have $z^n = r^n e^{in\theta}$, which is equal to the multiplicative identity $1$ if and only if $r = 1$ and $n\theta$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$; in other words, $\theta = 2k\pi/n$ for some integers $k,n$. Therefore, the elements with finite order are precisely those of the form $e^{i2k\pi/n}$.